# Splitting a file based on values next to matching pattern

Tags: awk, csplit

I am having a file input.txt which include ~50,000 rows and ~100 column. I want to split is according to matching entry followed by the matching patter. File separator are both space and tab.

input.txt

```
#information  
#dateofcreation  
#file type
AA  BB  CC DD EE FF GG HH II 
AA  bb  ac aD FF GG hg ad 
DA  ga  Dt pp Ee    FF gg pm    TT
DA  bR  AT GT Gg    FF GG Hb    Yh
NM  gt  Jh GT FF    hb TH KM MM
```

In the input file there a matching field FF in all the lines followed by the entry matches in some lines. I want to have three output file from this input file

GG.txt

```
AA  BB  CC DD EE FF GG HH II
AA  bb  ac aD FF GG hg ad
DA  bR  AT GT Gg    FF GG Hb Yh
```

gg.txt

```
DA  ga  Dt pp Ee    FF gg pm    TT
```

hb.txt

```
NM  gt  Jh GT FF    hb TH KM MM
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not clear. There's just ONE single EE entry. What is the "matching entry"? Why the trailing "DA" in the second line of GG.txt? Please rephrase.

Comment: @RudiC My apology. I made a mistake. The matching patter should be FF. I am editing the post. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: And the trailing `DA`?

Comment: @RudiC Looks like while copying the files, there happen something and DA move. My sincere apology for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
awk '
match ($0, /FF *[^ ]* /)        {FN = substr($0, RSTART+3, RLENGTH -4) ".txt"
                                 gsub (/ /, "", FN)
                                 print $0  >  FN
                                }
' file
```

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you what "RSTART+3, RLENGTH -4"?

Comment: `man awk`:              `match(s,r)  Returns  the  index of the first longest match of regular expression r in string s . . .  As a side effect, RSTART is set to the return value.  RLENGTH is set to the length of the match or -1 if no match.`   `+3` skips the `FF `,  `-4` accounts for that and the trailing space.